# How would I populate a vector with all the elements from a List of type system string while converting it to std::string?

Tags: string, lambda, c++-cli

I am trying to understand lambda functions better and would like some example of how I could add to a vector while converting System.String^ to std::string with such a Lambda example (If I am able to).

My current foreach:

```
List<String^>^ names = //Returning 'System.String' List from C#

    for each (System::String^ name in names)
    {
      std::string convertedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(name);
      nameObjects.push_back(MyObject(convertedString, "test"));
    }
```

But I would like to extend it to something like this (*My best guess but I am missing the logic to convert each element of "names" to a single string, this is where a Lambda would help me*):

```
    std::vector<nameObjects> testObjects{ std::begin(msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(names)), std::end(msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(names)) };
```

Comment: @Dan I am just trying to understand Lambdas better, and I thought this would be a good example since it includes conversions and pushing to a list with the elements of a list type.

I don't know what exactly you mean when you're talking about working well together, are you saying I can't convert to std::string while pushing to a vector with begin and end with a Lambda?

Comment: @Ðаn Great observation Dan. I know I am not showing any attempt at using a Lambda (Kinda obvious how I am asking how to learn), would you say that I am not allowed to ask how to learn? 

-Do you think you could help me with an example so I can better understand it, with the question that was asked about it?

-You're telling me to understand Lambdas better by not using them? :/

Comment: Dan, if you took a moment to read my question or my follow up to your first question you would know I am sticking with C++, BUT I would like to use this cli example to understand since it includes everything in one question to HELP me understand it perfectly. Would you mind helping me out with this question because you telling me how I should go about asking a question is not helping me, and wastes both of our time. -Thanks for any help this far.

Comment: I am not asking **"How can I learn Lambdas"**. Thanks for your help. 
To everyone else this question is still standing.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I understand this I will do more research on iterating over .NET lists in c++. I did ask this question for 2 reasons. 

In the example link you gave me I found: 

`std::for_each(mySystemString.begin(), mySystemString.end(), [](System::String) { /* Is it possible to convert System string to std*/ });`

Would that be a possibility, even if it's not a direct answer it still helps me to understand what is possible with CLI? 

I appreciate you explaining why I should stick with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out a way to make this work...it requires using the obscure [`cliext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157742.aspx) classes.

First, create a `cliext::vector`, there is an overload with takes an `IEnumerator`.

```
cliext::vector<String^> v_names(names);
```

Now, you can use `cliext::transform()` (not [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)) to do STL-style iteration, and create `MyObject` instances with a lambda

```
std::vector<MyObject> testObjects;
cliext::transform(v_names.begin(), v_names.end(), std::back_inserter(testObjects), [](String^ name)
{
    std::string convertedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(name);
    return MyObject(convertedString, "test");
});
```